# Semaforo en c# usando hilos

Tags: c#, hilos

Cuando inicio el hilo ni siquiera cambian las imágenes antes de que llegue al sleep, como pongo correctamente el hilo, o que cambio necesito hacer para que funcione?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace semaforo_hilos_1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public static int c = 1;
        public void Go()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                if (c == 1)
                {
                    pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.gris;
                    pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.gris;
                    pictureBox3.Image = Properties.Resources.verde;
                    c = 2;
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);

                }
                if (c == 2)
                {
                    pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.gris;
                    pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.amarillo;
                    pictureBox3.Image = Properties.Resources.gris;
                    c = 3;
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                }
                if (c == 3)
                {
                    pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.rojo;
                    pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.gris;
                    pictureBox3.Image = Properties.Resources.gris;
                    c = 1;
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                }

            }


        }

         public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
              Form1 obj = new Form1();
              Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(obj.Go));
              t1.Start();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: simplemente intento simular un semaforo con hilos, cada vez que hay un cambio de imagenes el los picturebox el hilo se duerme cierto tiempo, y asi pasa de color en color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema inmediato está en las líneas siguientes:

```
Form1 obj = new Form1();
Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(obj.Go));
```

Estás ejecutando el método `Go` en una instancia diferente de `Form1` que no está visible. Mas bien, debes ejecutar `Go` en la instancia corriente del formulario, o sea, `this`:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.Go));
```

Con este pequeño cambio, deberías notar que las cosas funcionan mejor.

---

Ahora bien, deseo avisarte que no es buena práctica manipular controles visuales desde un hilo cualquiera. Normalmente se debe hacer del hilo principal (UI thread). De lo contrario, a menudo te lanza error o puede haber comportamientos raros. Te aviso para que te vayas acostumbrando a usar las mejores prácticas.

En este caso, probablemente sería mejor usar un Timer, o algún mecanismo similar.

Asumiendo que le agregas un Timer a tu formulario, aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo se pudiera lograr lo mismo sin violar la regla básica de manipular los controles a partir del hilo principal solamente.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.CambiarImagenes();
        this.timer1.Interval = 3000;
        this.timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.CambiarImagenes();

        if (i >= 10)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }
    }

    private int i = 0;
    private int c = 1;

    private void CambiarImagenes()
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case 1:
                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.gris;
                pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.gris;
                pictureBox3.Image = Properties.Resources.verde;
                c = 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.gris;
                pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.amarillo;
                pictureBox3.Image = Properties.Resources.gris;
                c = 3;
                break;
            case 3:
                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.rojo;
                pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.gris;
                pictureBox3.Image = Properties.Resources.gris;
                c = 1;
                break;
        }

        i++;
    }
}
```